# How can I make a group of checkboxes mutually exclusive?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to make mutually exculsive checkboxes.  I have come across numerous examples that do it giving example of one checkbox group.
One example is at http://blog.schuager.com/2008/09/mutually-exclusive-checkboxes-with.html.

In my case, I have many checkbox groups on the same page, so I want it to work like [this example](http://student.zwebinfo.net/mmosby/project/mutexCheckbox.aspx).
An asp.net codebehind [example is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749960/make-two-checkbox-lists-mutually-exclusive), but I want to do it in client side code.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

i have decided to use the ajax mutually exclusive checkbox extender. 
The solutions given so far are basically based on radio buttons.
This link really helped me..http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-mutuallyexclusive-checkbox-extender

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use radio elements for this?

Comment: mutually exculsive checkboxes ----> Radiobuttons!

Comment: Andy..thats the requirement...i would have been happy to use radio buttons list :(..people cmon please remove downvote...somebody somewhere willsurely face this problem...it should have been and upvote ..:(

Comment: @sajad: I didn't down vote, but I do find it difficult to believe that mutually exclusive checkboxes would ever benefit anyone.

Comment: technically yes its hard to digest..but it is the user requirement .....to put it this way..is there any way to make radio button look like checkbox :) ..my problem would then be solved

Comment: You should go back to the client and say that they are breaking usability rules.

Comment: @sajad how about adding another radiobox option name "None" to indicate that the user does not choose anything?

Comment: @OnesimusUnbound : lolz..nice thought..but i want a checkbox only :)..

Comment: The annoying thing about radio buttons as opposed to checkboxes is the necessity to create a "None of the above" option for every single grouping, which presents its own usability problems. If a radio button is accidentally selected, the user must search for a "None of the above option" as there is no other way to deselect their choice. Really there needs to be something in between radio buttons and checkboxes.

Comment: for simple cases I used this this.checked && $(this).siblings(':checked').prop('checked', false);

Comment: I have used this because I have a situation where either zero or one choices being checked is OK, but more than one is not OK.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using Mutual Checkboxes when there is Radio button is a bad idea but still you can do this as follows

HTML

```
<div>    
    Red: <input id="chkRed" name="chkRed" type="checkbox" value="red" class="checkbox">
    Blue: <input id="chkBlue" name="chkBlue" type="checkbox" value="blue" class="checkbox">
    Green: <input id="chkGreen" name="chkGreen" type="checkbox" value="green" class="checkbox">
</div>

<div>
    Mango: <input id="chkRed" name="chkMango" type="checkbox" value="Mango" class="checkbox">
    Orange: <input id="chkBlue" name="chkOrange" type="checkbox" value="Orange" class="checkbox">
    Banana: <input id="chkGreen" name="chkBanana" type="checkbox" value="Banana" class="checkbox">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('div .checkbox').click(function () { 
                 checkedState = $(this).attr('checked');
                  $(this).parent('div').children('.checkbox:checked').each(function () {
                      $(this).attr('checked', false);
                  });
                  $(this).attr('checked', checkedState);
});
```

And here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fb2CV/1/)

Answer (score 14):

Like I said in my comment, you should really use `<radio>` elements for this.  Give them the same name and they work almost the same way:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="Option 1">Option 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="Option 2">Option 2</label>
```

The only significant difference is that, once one of them is selected, at least one of them has to be on (ie, you can't uncheck them again).

If you really feel the need to do it with check boxes, remind yourself that users with JavaScript disabled will be able to select all the options if they like.  If you *still* feel the need to do it, then you'll need to give each checkbox group a unique class name.  Then, handle the change event of each checkbox element and uncheck all the other elements matching the same class name as the clicked element.

Comment: +1. He may also modify their look in JS so that they look like check boxes if he really needs to (though I'm not sure it's a good idea), cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox. As for the uncheck behavior, a workaround may be to provide a radio button with a default (empty?) value.

Comment: @Shautieh: yes, I was thinking about recommending styling radio elements too, but it's difficult to achieve in a cross-browser manner.

Comment: One possible scenario for radiobuttons not useful is when you need to uncheck them

Comment: @Daniel: and the norm for that is to have a "None" radio option.  Again, I just don't think there's *ever* a good reason for using checkboxes and javascript to do a radio group's job.

Comment: @AndyE When you need to select multiple inputs with the same name. With checkboxes it's possible. With radios, it's not. Example: you have a list of 100 people and want to mark the gender (like Male or Female). A single name="male" for all checks is enough, same for female.

Comment: @Gustavo that won't do what you think it does. When multiple for elements have the same name, a standard HTML form submission will result in the last element's value being sent, overriding the values of all those before.

Comment: @AndyE I'm quite sure you can send multiple values on a single name with checkboxes. I do this and in my java backend I just do request.getParameterValues("inputName") and I get a list of values. The backend in this case has nothing to do with this. It just gets what the browser sends. Maybe the browsers do more than the "standard HTML form submission".

Comment: My bad, I haven't written a form submission script for several years now :)

Answer (score 7):

I hope [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mv2hb/) one will work

*HTML*

```
A <input type="checkbox" class="alpha" value="A" /> | 
B <input type="checkbox" class="alpha" value="B" /> | 
C <input type="checkbox" class="alpha" value="C" /> 
<br />

1 <input type="checkbox" class="num" value="1" /> |
2 <input type="checkbox" class="num" value="2" /> |
3 <input type="checkbox" class="num" value="3" />
```

*JavaScript*

```
// include jQuery library
var enforeMutualExcludedCheckBox = function(group){
    return function() {
      var isChecked= $(this).prop("checked");
      $(group).prop("checked", false);
      $(this).prop("checked", isChecked);
    }
};

$(".alpha").click(enforeMutualExcludedCheckBox(".alpha"));
$(".num").click(enforeMutualExcludedCheckBox(".num"));
```

well, radio button should be the one to be used in mutually excluded options, though I've encountered a scenario where the client preferred to have zero to one selected item, and the javaScript'ed checkbox works well.

*Update*

Looking at my answer, I realized it's redundant to refer to the css class twice. I updated my code to convert it into a jquery plugin, and created two solutions, depending on ones preference

**Get all checkboxes whose check is mutually excluded**

```
$.fn.mutuallyExcludedCheckBoxes = function(){
    var $checkboxes = this; // refers to selected checkboxes

    $checkboxes.click(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          isChecked = $this.prop("checked");

      $checkboxes.prop("checked", false);
      $this.prop("checked", isChecked);
    });
};

// more elegant, just invoke the plugin
$("[name=alpha]").mutuallyExcludedCheckBoxes();
$("[name=num]").mutuallyExcludedCheckBoxes();
```

HTML

```
A <input type="checkbox" name="alpha" value="A" /> | 
B <input type="checkbox" name="alpha" value="B" /> | 
C <input type="checkbox" name="alpha" value="C" /> 
<br />

1 <input type="checkbox" name="num" value="1" /> |
2 <input type="checkbox" name="num" value="2" /> |
3 <input type="checkbox" name="num" value="3" />
```

[sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/mv2hb/31/)

**Group all mutually excluded checkboxes in a containing element**

JavaScript

```
$.fn.mutuallyExcludedCheckBoxes = function(){
    var $checkboxes = this.find("input[type=checkbox]");

    $checkboxes.click(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
          isChecked = $this.prop("checked");

      $checkboxes.prop("checked", false);
      $this.prop("checked", isChecked);
    });
};

// select the containing element, then trigger the plugin 
// to set all checkboxes in the containing element mutually 
// excluded
$(".alpha").mutuallyExcludedCheckBoxes();
$(".num").mutuallyExcludedCheckBoxes();
```

HTML

```
<div class="alpha">
A <input type="checkbox" value="A" /> | 
B <input type="checkbox" value="B" /> | 
C <input type="checkbox" value="C" /> 
</div>

<div class="num">
1 <input type="checkbox" value="1" /> |
2 <input type="checkbox" value="2" /> |
3 <input type="checkbox" value="3" /> 
</div>
```

[sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/mv2hb/29/)

Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div>
    Car: <input id="chkVehicleCar" name="chkVehicle" type="checkbox" value="Car" class="radiocheckbox">
    Moto: <input id="chkVehicleMoto" name="chkVehicle" type="checkbox" value="Moto" class="radiocheckbox">
    Byke: <input id="chkVehicleByke" name="chkVehicle" type="checkbox" value="Byke" class="radiocheckbox">
    Feet: <input id="chkVehicleFeet" name="chkVehicle" type="checkbox" value="Feet">
</div>

<span>    
    Red: <input id="chkColorRed" name="chkColor" type="checkbox" value="Red" class="radiocheckbox">
    Blue: <input id="chkColorBlue" name="chkColor" type="checkbox" value="Blue" class="radiocheckbox">
    Green: <input id="chkColorGreen" name="chkColor" type="checkbox" value="Green" class="radiocheckbox">

    Mango: <input id="chkFruitMango" name="chkFruit" type="checkbox" value="Mango" class="radiocheckbox">
    Orange: <input id="chkFruitOrange" name="chkFruit" type="checkbox" value="Orange" class="radiocheckbox">
    Banana: <input id="chkFruitBanana" name="chkFruit" type="checkbox" value="Banana" class="radiocheckbox">
</span>
```

​JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(':checkbox.radiocheckbox').click(function() {
    this.checked
        && $(this).siblings('input[name="' + this.name + '"]:checked.' + this.className)
                  .prop('checked', false);
});​
```

Mutually exclusive checkboxes are grouped by container+name+classname.
You can use different groups in same container and also mix exclusive with non-exclusive checkbox with same name.
JavaScript code is highly optimized. You can see a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/4d5T9/9/).

Answer (score 2):

No matter where the check box is located on your page, you just need to specify the group and here you go!

```
    <input type='checkbox' data-group='orderState'> pending
    <input type='checkbox' data-group='orderState'> solved
    <input type='checkbox' data-group='orderState'> timed out

    <input type='checkbox' data-group='sex'> male
    <input type='checkbox' data-group='sex'> female

    <input type='checkbox'> Isolated


    <script>
       $(document).ready(function () {
          $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
            var state = $(this)[0].checked, 
                g = $(this).data('group');
             $(this).siblings()
             .each(function () {
     $(this)[0].checked = g==$(this).data('group')&&state ? false : $(this)[0].checked;
             });
  });
 })</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want.

Consider the **HTML** below:

```
<form action="">
    My favourite colors are:<br />
    <br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="red" name="color" /> Red<br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="yellow" name="color" /> Yellow<br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="blue" name="color" /> Blue<br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="orange" name="color1" /> Orange<br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="green" name="color1" /> Green<br />
    <input type="checkbox" value="purple" name="color1" /> Purple
</form>
```

Note that there's two names for color groups: `red, yellow, blue` and `orage, green, purple`

And this JavaScript noted below will work generically to all `checkbox` on the page.

```
jQuery("input[type=checkbox]").unbind("click");
jQuery("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index, value) {
    var checkbox = jQuery(value);
    checkbox.bind("click", function () {
        var check = checkbox.attr("checked");
        jQuery("input[name=" + checkbox.attr('name') + "]").prop("checked", false);
        checkbox.attr("checked", check);
    });
});
```

Take a look at this [LIVE example](http://jsfiddle.net/xucAY/)