# Making two exclusive checkbox inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have followed this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fb2CV/1/) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077919/how-can-i-make-a-group-of-checkboxes-mutually-exclusive).

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="paramStart">
    <div id="gameType">
    <div id="UserVsComputer" class="checkbox" style="margin-left: 8px;">                 
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="">User vs Computer</label>                    
    </div>
    <br>                                                                                 
    <br>
    <div id="User1VsUser2" class="checkbox" style="margin-left: 8px;">                   
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="">User1 vs User2</label>                      
    </div>                                                                               
</div>
```

I did in JavaScript:

```
var gameType = document.getElementById('gameType');

gameType.addEventListener('click', setGameType, false);

function setGameType() {

  var checkInput = $('#gameType .checkbox > label > input');
  console.log(checkInput);
  checkedState = checkInput.attr('checked');
  checkInput.attr('checked').each(function () {
      $(this).attr('checked', false);
  }); 
  checkInput.attr('checked', checkedState);

  }
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: checkInput.attr(...) is undefined
```

I try to access the `<input> tag` for setting true to the clicked `<input>`

Where is my error?

### Update

@Mohamed-Yousef

To get the array of checked inputs, I did:

```
var checkInput = $('#gameType > div > input[type="checkbox"]');
console.log(checkInput.attr());
```

I get:

```
TypeError: a is undefined jquery-latest.min.js:4:9978
```

Comment: So erm mutually exclusive checkboxes have a name you know. Radio buttons. Like in `<input type="radio">`.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes that is what I asked for in my last comment

Comment: Note that referenced fiddle MIGHT use: `$('div').on('click', '.checkbox', function() {
  $(this).siblings('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This entire thing can be simply:

NOT capturing the current state:

```
$('#gameType').on('click','.checkbox',function(){
    $(this).siblings().find('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked = false;
});
```

OR

```
$('#gameType').on('click','.checkbox',function(){
    $(this).siblings().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Un-check the other box no matter what the current checkbox state is:

```
$('#gameType').on('click','.checkbox',function(){
    var checkBoxState = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked;
    $(this).siblings().find('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked = false;
});
```

OR

Make the OTHER checkbox the opposite of this one:(NOTE: both cannot be "unchecked" using this.)

```
$('#gameType').on('click','.checkbox',function(){
    var checkBoxState = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked;
    console.log(checkBoxState);
    $(this).siblings().find('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked = !checkBoxState;
});
```

EDIT: Note that this way, you can click the label as well as the checkbox which might enhance the user experience but you would need to decide that.

IF the syntax above is not desired you can also manage the property with jQuery as:

```
$(this).siblings().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", false);
```

OR

EDIT: Here, we then use the `.prop()` to both get and set:

```
$('#gameType').on('click','.checkbox',function(){
    var checkBoxState = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked");
    console.log(checkBoxState);
    $(this).siblings().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checkBoxState);
});
```

EDIT: here is another method using `.is()`

```
$('#gameType').on('click','.checkbox',function(){
    var checkBoxState = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked");
    console.log(checkBoxState);
    $(this).siblings().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", checkBoxState);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

up to your html structure you can change the game type when user checked the checkbox and unchecked another one

```
var gameType = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

gameType.on('click', function(){
   setGameType($(this));
});

function setGameType(el) {
  if(el.is(':checked')){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(el).prop('checked' , false);
  }
}
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/1d1kajyx/)

and about your code

```
$('#gameType .checkbox > label > input').attr();
```

Its an array of inputs not just one input to get attr for.. You can use it inside .each to get attr for each checkbox by using

```
checkInput.each(function () {
     alert( $(this).attr('checked'));
  });
```

Comment: What does "not(el)" means ? I guess it is the other input but what's the value of "not(el)" ? thanks

Comment: @user1773603 that means avoid this element to checked it to false like others ... in another way .. checked false all inputs but not this input

Comment: @user1773603 so if you try to delete .not(el) from the code you can no longer check the input .. cause it will checked false all the input plus the input you click on

Comment: @user1773603 but let me ask .. while you need user to select just one type of game   why you didn't used radio inputs instead of checkbox

Comment: I saw there was this solution with radio inputs but I have not tested it. And for my issue, I still have a "TypeError: checkInput.attr(...) is undefined" at the line "checkInput.attr('checked').each(function () {" taking var checkInput = $('#gameType > input[type="checkbox"]');

Comment: @user1773603 sorry I deleted from my answer .. as I said in answer you cant get attr() for array of inputs

Comment: `.attr("checked")` always returns the initial state of the check ("checked" or "undefined") - use `.prop("checked");` = see here for the console log: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/x6j1ewzq/ - the first one is checked the second is undefined